# How to Change a Views Scale Value without Actually Scaling it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm wondering if it possible to actually change a UIViews scale value without actually scaling it? For instance, how do you change this `transform.scale` value:

```
[[[[myView] layer] valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];
```

My reason for doing this is pretty ocdish. I have an application where I import an image that the user can drag around the screen and scale. When the image is imported, I initially have to scale it and center it to fit within the view. When I scale it, it's "transform.scale" value changes from 1 to whatever I scale it too. There is a work around this if I do the scaling by setting the frame instead of doing `CGAffineTransformScale`. However, I'd like to avoid that and would simply just like to reset the scale value to 1 somehow.

Comment: confusing... I'm not getting you?

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore When you do a CGAffineTransformScale on a view, it changes that value I listed above, the valueForKeyPath one. So if it initially is 1, and I minimize down to half its size, the scale will go down to like .5. I want to reset the scale value to 1, so future scales are in terms of the scale I just performed, not the original value.

Comment: Ok..let me see if I can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reset`the scale to 1 once you have scaled it, however you could have an`initialScale`variable and store this initial scale. When the user starts to scale after that, simply apply the scale factor to this`initialScale` to get the actual scale.

So for example, you scale the image initially to fit and it has a scale of 0.8 set `initialScale` to 0.8.

When the user starts to scale the image down from 1 to 0.5 for instance, apply this change to your initial scale, so user scales to 0.5, multiply the initial scale by this which equals 0.4.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm doing now, just looking for a way that I can avoid using a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the UIView [contentScaleFactor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentScaleFactor) property. Like the view's transform, contentScaleFactor changes the view's display size relative to other views and does not affect its user coordinate size (i.e., position, bounds, frame). With the difference that contentScaleFactor changes the actual size of the view backing store bitmap, where transform scaling does not.